# Can't pass all test cases for LeetCode question to find intersection of two linked lists using Hash map

Tags: c++, linked-list, hashtable, unordered-map

I passed the initial test case but it is showing wrong answer for a test case.( Linked lists given in test case : [0,9,1,2,4] and [3,2,4]. The expected answer is node with value 2 but i am getting 4.) Can anyone spot error in the code?

Other ways of doing the problem are welcomed but i wanted to do this with Hash map for my own practice.

```
class Solution{
    public:
            ListNode *getIntersectionNode(ListNode *headA, ListNode *headB) {
                    unordered_map<int, ListNode*> map;
                    int i=0;
                    while(headA!=NULL){ //inserting all nodes of LL A in hash map
                            map[i]=headA;
                            headA=headA->next;
                            i++;
                    }

                    while(1){
                            for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); it++) {
                                    if (it->second == headB){
                                            return it->second;
                                    }
                                    else{
                                            if(headB->next!=NULL) {
                                                    headB=headB->next;
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
                    return NULL;
            }
};
```

Comment: Well, for one the code isn't formatted consistently, which will turn away many people that would otherwise take a look at it. Anyhow, please check [tour] and [ask] and extract a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to preface this by saying that an `unordered_map` has no guarantees of storage order. This means that items aren't necessarily stored in the same order as they are inserted.
Let's look at the relevant code.

```
while(1){
      for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); it++) {
          if (it->second == headB){
              return it->second;
          }
          else{
              if(headB->next!=NULL) {
                  headB=headB->next;
              }
              else{
                  break;
              }
          }
}
```

The iterator is going to loop through the map's stored order in an order you essentially cannot predict. From a cursory glance of your code, I can see that your program is going to return in one of the following two cases:

- If the random order the iterator goes through the map happens to have
  a value that lines up with a corresponding `headB` value.
- If `headB` reaches it's last value without finding a match, the `while(1)` would restart the inner for loop and would compare the first value pointed at by the iterator to the last value in the `headB` linked list. If that comparison succeeds, then the program would return. Otherwise, the loop goes on forever.